# Equation: boxed split inside align

Tags: equations, align, split, box

How to box the second `split` environment ?

Bonus: to box only a part of the `split` environment content it so I can add a `\Longleftrightarrow` before the box.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        A ={}& B + C + D
    \end{split}\nonumber\\
    \begin{split}
        A ={}& \phantom{{}+{}} B\_is\_long\\
             &            +    C\_is\_long\_too\\
             &            +    D\_is\_long\_too
    \end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

MWE:
[image: MWE]

What I'm looking for :
[image: What I want]

Answer (score 7):

You can customize the output, but the idea is simple with `hf-tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
A ={}& B + C + D \notag \\
\begin{split}
\tikzmarkin{thisbox}
A ={}& \phantom{{}+{}} B\_is\_long\\
  &            +    C\_is\_long\_too\\
  &            +    D\_is\_long\_too\tikzmarkend{thisbox}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use `aligned` instead of `split` environments, as one can encase an `aligned` environment -- but not a `split` environment -- in a `\boxed` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for longer "underscore" characters
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    &\kern\fboxsep\kern\fboxrule % take care to align the "A"s
     \begin{aligned}
         A ={}& B + C + D
     \end{aligned}\nonumber\\
    & \boxed{\begin{aligned}
        A ={}& \phantom{{}+{}} B\_is\_long      \\
             &            +    C\_is\_long\_too \\
             &            +    D\_is\_long\_too
    \end{aligned}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A follow-up comment: The first of the two `aligned` environments isn't needed. I didn't remove the redundant code, though, in the answer shown above as I assume that in your real document, the first of two `split`/`aligned` environments does serve a useful purpose.

Answer (score 2):

hope it will help

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \begin{split}
        A ={}& B + C + D
    \end{split}\nonumber\\
\end{align*}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}   
    \begin{split}
        A ={}& \phantom{{}+{}} B\_is\_long\\
             &            +    C\_is\_long\_too\\
             &            +    D\_is\_long\_too
    \end{split}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: alignment with the first = is lost

Comment: There's also too much space between the two blocks.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to overlap blank `\boxed{}` on top of your expression, which takes the same space as the original expression itself. This can be achieved by both `\mathrlap{}` (from `mathtools`) and `\phantom{}`

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        A ={}& B + C + D
    \end{split}\nonumber\\
  \mathrlap{\boxed{\phantom{\begin{gathered}A = {}+ C\_is\_long\_too\\A\\A\end{gathered}}}}
  \hspace{\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule-0.4pt}
  \begin{split}
        A ={}& \phantom{{}+{}} B\_is\_long\\
             &            +    C\_is\_long\_too\\
             &            +    D\_is\_long\_too
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While being an impressive work-out, it's obviously too much complex.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for pointing at this. I removed misleading and confusing parts.